# Is there a way to subtract from a number that is in a txt file c#

Tags: c#, text-files, subtraction

Hi I am New to C# and could do with some help. I have a programme that currently save`s Events to there own text file which contains the details about the event(the details are entered by the user). One of these details is The Amount Of tickets. I am having trouble with making it so that when a ticket is brought the amount decreases by one.

I would like to Know If there Is Anyway For me to subtract 1 from a Number that is on a Text File.
this is how my Text Files Are laid out:

```
Event Name: Test
Event Time: 12:30
Event Location: Test
Amount Of Tickets: 120
Price Of Tickets: £5
```

This is the method i tried and all this did was add -1 -1 to the value instead of taking away from the value:

```
Console.WriteLine("What Event Would You Like To Buy A Ticket For?");
            string EventUpdate = Console.ReadLine(); 
            string folderPath = (@"A:\Work\Visual Studio\TextFiles");
            string fileName = EventUpdate + ".txt";
            string filePath = folderPath + "\\" + fileName;  //creats file path using FolderPath Plus users Input
            string Contents = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            Console.WriteLine(Contents); //displays the txt file that was called for
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            string FindText = "Amount Of Tickets:";
            int I = -1;
            string NewText = FindText + I;
            string NewTempFile = folderPath + EventUpdate + ".txt";
            string file = filePath;
            File.WriteAllText(file, File.ReadAllText(file).Replace(FindText, NewText));


            using (var sourceFile = File.OpenText(file))
            {
                // Create a temporary file path where we can write modify lines
                string tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), NewTempFile);
                // Open a stream for the temporary file
                using (var tempFileStream = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
                {
                    string line;
                    // read lines while the file has them
                    while ((line = sourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        // Do the Line replacement
                        line = line.Replace(FindText, NewText);
                        // Write the modified line to the new file
                        tempFileStream.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Replace the original file with the temporary one
            File.Replace(NewTempFile, file, null);
```

this is what happened to my text file when i used the above code:

```
 Event Name: Test
 Event Time: 12:30
 Event Location: Test
 Amount Of Tickets:-1-1 120
 Price Of Tickets: £5
```

Comment: Its helpful if you can explain exactly what you want to do, i am guessing you want to minus `1` from `Amount Of Tickets: 120` and write it to a new file? so it reads `Amount Of Tickets: 119` ?

Comment: yes that`s exactly what i would like to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are oodles of way to do this... However, you need to convert a your "text number" to an actual number (in this case an `integer`) to perform mathematical operations on it

```
// get the lines in an array
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

// iterate through every line
for (var index = 0; index < lines.Length; index++)
{
   // does the line start with the text you expect?
   if (lines[index].StartsWith(findText))
   {
      // awesome, lets split it apart
      var parts = lines[index].Split(':');
      // part 2 (index 1) has your number
      var num = int.Parse(parts[1].Trim());
      // recreate the line minus 1
      lines[index] = $"{findText} {num-1}";
      // no more processing needed
      break;
   }    
}
// write the lines to the file
File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
```

***Note*** : even if this doesn't work (and i haven't checked it) you should have enough information to continue unaided

---

**Additional Resources**

[String.StartsWith Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Determines whether the beginning of this string instance matches a
>   specified string.

[String.Split Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode
>   character array.

[String.Trim Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns a new string in which all leading and trailing occurrences of
>   a set of specified characters from the current String object are
>   removed.

[Int32.Parse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent.

[File.ReadAllLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file into a string array,
>   and then closes the file.

[File.WriteAllLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Creates a new file, writes one or more strings to the file, and then
>   closes the file.

[$ - string interpolation (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

> The $ special character identifies a string literal as an interpolated
>   string. An interpolated string is a string literal that might contain
>   interpolated expressions. When an interpolated string is resolved to a
>   result string, items with interpolated expressions are replaced by the
>   string representations of the expression results. This feature is
>   available in C# 6 and later versions of the language.

Comment: Thank you TheGeneral, this code works exactly how i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm attaching a modified version of your code with coments added which works

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace New_Folder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What Event Would You Like To Buy A Ticket For?");
            string EventUpdate = Console.ReadLine();
            string folderPath = ("TextFiles");
            string fileName = EventUpdate + ".txt";
            string filePath = fileName; //creats file path using FolderPath Plus users Input
            string[] Contents = File.ReadAllLines(filePath); //Puts each line content into array element

            foreach (var line in Contents)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(line); //displays the txt file that was called for
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n");

            int LineWithAmountOfTicketIndex = 3;
            string LineWithAmountOfTicketText = Contents[LineWithAmountOfTicketIndex];

            string[] AmountLineContent = LineWithAmountOfTicketText.Split(':'); // Splits text by ':' sign and puts elements into an array, e.g. "one:two" would be split into "one" and "two"
            int TicketNumber = Int32.Parse(AmountLineContent[1]); // Parses the ticket number part from a string to int (check out TryParse() as well)
            int SubtractedTicketNumber = --TicketNumber; //subtract one from ticket number before assigning to a variable

            string NewText = $"{AmountLineContent[0]}: {SubtractedTicketNumber}";
            string NewTempFile = folderPath + EventUpdate + ".txt";
            string file = filePath;
            File.WriteAllText(file, File.ReadAllText(file).Replace(LineWithAmountOfTicketText, NewText));

            using(var sourceFile = File.OpenText(file))
            {
                // Create a temporary file path where we can write modify lines
                string tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), NewTempFile);
                // Open a stream for the temporary file
                using(var tempFileStream = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
                {
                    string line;
                    // read lines while the file has them
                    while ((line = sourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        // Do the Line replacement
                        line = line.Replace(LineWithAmountOfTicketText, NewText);
                        // Write the modified line to the new file
                        tempFileStream.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Replace the original file with the temporary one
            File.Replace(NewTempFile, file, null);
        }
    }
}
```